# Declaring an array of objects in a Spring bean context

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

I'm trying to create an array of objects in a Spring context file so I can inject it to a constructor that's declared like this:

```
public RandomGeocodingService(GeocodingService... services) { }
```

I'm trying to use the `<array>` tag:

```
<bean id="googleGeocodingService" class="geocoding.GoogleGeocodingService">
 <constructor-arg ref="proxy" />
 <constructor-arg value="" />
</bean>

<bean id="geocodingService" class="geocoding.RandomGeocodingService">
    <constructor-arg>
        <array value-type="geocoding.GeocodingService">
            <!-- How do I reference the google geocoding service here? -->
        </array>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

I haven't been able to find an example or something in the in the documentation on how to do this. Also, you have any suggestions for a better way of acheiving what I'm trying to do, please let me know :).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

That's because there's no such thing as `<array>`, there's only `<list>`.

The good news is that Spring will auto-convert between lists and arrays as required, so defined your array as a `<list>`, and Spring will be coerce it into an array for you.

This should work:

```
<bean id="googleGeocodingService" class="geocoding.GoogleGeocodingService">
   <constructor-arg ref="proxy" />
   <constructor-arg value="" />
</bean>

<bean id="geocodingService" class="geocoding.RandomGeocodingService">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
           <ref bean="googleGeocodingService"/>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Spring will also coerce a single bean into a list, if required:

```
<bean id="geocodingService" class="geocoding.RandomGeocodingService">
    <constructor-arg>
       <ref bean="googleGeocodingService"/>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 8):

Spring can automatically convert a list into an array[]

check it out http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?37767-Injecting-String-Array

```
<bean name="test" class="Test">
   <property name="values" value="hugo,emil"></property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 5):

Check out the [util schema](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-config.html#xsd-config-body-schemas-util).

Answer (score 5):

I'm actually using `<array>` tag to inject an array of objects into a bean and it works.

Take a look at the following code...

```
    <bean id="song1" class="mx.com.company.songs.Song">
        <property name="name" value="Have you ever seen the rain?"/>        
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="song2" class="mx.com.company.songs.Song">
        <property name="name" value="La bamba"/>      
    </bean>

    <bean id="guitarPlayer" class="mx.com.company.musician.GuitarPlayer">
        <property name="songs">
            <array>
                <ref bean="song1"/>
                <ref bean="song2"/>
            </array>
        </property>
    </bean>
```